# Flatten list of list of strings into single comma separated list

Tags: java, collections

How would I convert a list of list of strings into a single comma separated list (flatten the lists in one)? Eg:

```
[[[B1, TMC, Streampix], [HSD1, Streampix - HSD], [CDV1, CDV2]]]
```

into

```
[B1, TMC, Streampix], [HSD1, Streampix - HSD], [CDV1, CDV2]
```

Comment: What is a comma-separated List?

Answer (score 2):

It becomes really easy using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) streams.

Stream over each list, convert it to a string separated by commas and then collect them all in a big list.

```
List<String> newList = list.stream()
                           .map(x -> x.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

newList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

### Output

```
B1,TMC,Streampix
HSD1,Streampix - HSD
CDV1,CDV2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use StringUtils.join() method if you have Apache Commons Lang lib

suppose list has following element

```
 List list = [[["B1", "TMC", "Streampix"], ["HSD1", "Streampix - HSD"], ["CDV1", "CDV2"]]]
```

then :

```
String strList = StringUtils.join(list,',');
System.out.println(strList);
```

output :

```
[[B1, TMC, Streampix], [HSD1, Streampix - HSD], [CDV1, CDV2]]
```

for the reference see link [How to convert a List<String> list to csv string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414935/how-to-convert-a-liststring-list-to-csv-string)

Hope this will help you...:)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually really simple.

You can actually create an arraylist of arraylists! Then print that out with a loop and it will be in the format you want automatically

Here is an example I think may help you.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> list = new ArrayList();//create a list of lists
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList();//sample data
ArrayList<String> test2 = new ArrayList();//sample data

test.add("Test");//add sample data to list
test.add("Test");
test.add("Test");
test2.add("Test");
test2.add("Test");
test2.add("Test");

list.add(test);//ad sample lists to main list
list.add(test2);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)//this is what you want for your list
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
```

This has an output of

> [Test, Test, Test] 
>     [Test, Test, Test] instead of [[Test, Test, Test],[Test, Test, Test]]

Comment: This is fine for printing. I want to capture the details and send to another function.

Comment: use string buffer and append every detail to buffer and send that buffer to other function

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
//inputList is your List of List of String
List<String> retval = new ArrayList<>();
for(List<String> l : inputList){
    retval.add(l.toString());
}
```

then the retval = `[B1, TMC, Streampix], [HSD1, Streampix - HSD], [CDV1, CDV2]`

Comment: Still the final value is [[[B1, TMC, Streampix], [HSD1, Streampix - HSD], [CDV1, CDV2]]]